# Kendo UI listBox mvvm drag and drop not working

Tags: kendo-ui

I am implementing kendo grid drag and using in java script using MVVM like discussed in this example in documentation.

https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/listbox/drag-and-drop

The example above is written is not written in *mvvm pattern*(adding data-properties pattern) so the link below i have tried to convert into mvvm style pattern but drag and drop does not work for some reason and no error on console.

[Dojo implementation of Current Code](https://dojo.telerik.com/OcOreniw)

Any help or guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change data-drop-sources attribute value

from: `data-drop-sources="listbox2"`

to: `data-drop-sources="['listbox2']"`

Everything else is good.
I updated your [dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/OcOreniw/6) example and its working fine.

Comment: @adDev  thanks . Can you explain it little bit more ? I some time miss these nested syntax

Comment: Since you can have multiple drop targets it accepts an array of multiple ids. E.g. You can have another listbox 'listbox3' and drag to that as well.

Comment: ok thanks . I understood that just adding quotes ' is sometime confusing when converting code to mvvm pattern